# IntelliJ Idea glassfish runtime library support

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, intellij-idea

i love IntelliJ Idea IDE but there is one thing that keeps me from using it for GlassFish applications. I can't seem to find a way to use libraries from glassfish runtime in my projects. Could anybody help me with that? I know it's possible to do in NetBeans but that IDE looks really dumb once you try Idea (no offense to NetBeans lovers :).

I tried to import those libraries through Project Structure->Modules->Dependencies->Add->GlassFish but that only found ejb,servlet and jsp library.

Any help would be really appriciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that GlassFish application server classpath contains all the required jars, you can add missing jars manually in **Settings | Application Servers | GlassFish**.